# Can ocamldoc reference type constructors?

Tags: ocaml, documentation-generation, ocamldoc

I'm trying to refer to a type constructor in ocamldoc.

For example:

```
type x = Awesome | Boring
```

And later we want to refer to one of the constructors in some documentation:

```
(** {!Awesome} is a really great constructor for {!x}.  You should definitely use it instead of {!Boring}. *)
```

ocamldoc complains:

```
Warning: Element Awesome not found
Warning: Element Boring not found
```

Is there a way to reference type constructors such that ocamldoc can link to the corresponding type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly cross-link to a type constructor. However, you can link to the type itself:

```
(** {{!x}Awesome} is a really great constructor for {!x}. *)
```

If you want to have something more precise, you can write a small ocamldoc plugin to overwrite the `html_of_Ref` method.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK that's not possible. You can see the kind of references that can be made with this syntax [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual029.html#htoc175). However what you can do is :

```
(** {{!x}[Awesome]} that will at least bring to {!x} by clicking on it. *)
```